# Mysql Syntax error for spree migrations on heroku

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku, spree, cleardb

So, I am using `spree 3.7` and tried to deploy my rails 5.2.3 application on heroku with `clearDB` addon for MySQL support. But everytime i ran migrations, syntax error pops up.

```
 Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
 check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) NOT NULL, `updated_at` datetime(6) NOT NULL,  INDEX `index_spree_addresses_o' at line 1
```

The corresponding table schema (generated by spree) is below:

```
create_table "spree_addresses", id: :integer, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "firstname"
t.string "lastname"
t.string "address1"
t.string "address2"
t.string "city"
t.string "zipcode"
t.string "phone"
t.string "state_name"
t.string "alternative_phone"
t.string "company"
t.integer "state_id"
t.integer "country_id"
t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
t.index ["country_id"], name: "index_spree_addresses_on_country_id"
t.index ["firstname"], name: "index_addresses_on_firstname"
t.index ["lastname"], name: "index_addresses_on_lastname"
t.index ["state_id"], name: "index_spree_addresses_on_state_id"
end
```

Gemfile for references:

```
gem 'spree_multi_vendor', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_multi_vendor'
gem 'spree', '~> 3.7.0'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 3.5'
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.4'
```

I don't see any logical error as the same was running just good in my local. Any Idea ??

Comment: I am not sure but can you try t.timestamp in place of t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false and t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false

Comment: But the error was coming during the index creation. check that..

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar issue with spree plugin. Ended up changing the ClearDB to JawsDB.